# How to enable javascript in client machine using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Is there any way to enable JavaScript on the client machine using PHP?

Comment: 53% is pretty acceptable, IMO.

Comment: Why in the world would I trust anybody who wants to run software on my computer against my will?  You're talking about writing malware there, even if it doesn't look like it to you.  If you could do what you asked, so could anybody else, and it could be used for all sorts of malicious purposes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't do such a thing. It's impossible to modify user preferences stored on their local machines.

You can ask them to enable javascript if it's not the case using the [noscript](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_noscript.asp) tag.

Answer (score 5):

No, as neither the HTTP protocol or HTML have a feature to do this. To have a website able to enable JavaScript would also be a breach of security. There is also no guarentee that the users browser has JavaScript.

You may wish to look at the <noscript> tags, which allow you to display a message to the user when JavaScript is not active.